# Find the surface area of the portion of the cone $z^2=x^2+y^2$ that is inside the cylinder $z^2=2y$.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, surface-integrals

(1) I have solved the problem, but I am not sure about the number of octants the surface covers (this affects the final answer value).

(2) Also, I have questions regarding the intersection of the two surfaces. On which plane does this intersection lie?

Intersection of the two surfaces is a unit circle: $x^2 + (y-1)^2 = 1$. On which
plane does this intersection lie? Not able to visualize this.

I considered the surface $S: z = \sqrt{x^2+y^2} = f(x,y)$. So, $dS = \sqrt{1 + f_x^2 + f_y^2} dxdy$

$dS = \sqrt2 dx dy.$

So the required surface area is $2\iint dS$.  (Since the intersection of surface $S$ & the cylinder 
covers 2 octants, while the intersection of the surface $z = - \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$
& the cylinder covers another two octants. Is this reasoning correct?)

So, final answer is $2\iint dS = 2\sqrt2 \iint dx dy = 2\sqrt2 \pi$.

Comment: Yes, it is correct. The top part is a surface hanging above xy-plane and projected into the disk on xy-plane. The bottom is symmetric to that.

Comment: Okay, and what about the plane of intersection? For which value of z do the two surfaces intersect? Couldn't figure that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about two circles attached at the origin. One opens toward above xy-plane, the other opens downward below xy-plane. The z value depends on the xy values when you traverse the circle.

You can change to cylindrical coordinate:

$$x=\cos{\theta}, y=\sin{\theta}+1$$

Then use either one of the equations to express $z$ in terms of $\theta$. That will be the parametric equation of the intersection plane.

I couldn't get a better picture. See below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this picture, at least now I can visualize the intersection to some extent.